# Django Background Process Not Working Properly

Tags: python, django, background-process, django-celery

I am trying to install django-background-task to run some simple background tasks after a response is sent to the user. However, I am not able to run migrations, "python manage.py makemigrations background_task" gives an error. After installation actually I get an error,

`File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 203, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 107, in load_disk
    for name in os.listdir(directory):
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/root/.venvs/netadc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_background_tasks-1.1.13-py2.7.egg/background_task/migrations'`

I am not sure what I am missing. These are pretty simple steps. I installed the package from source and installed the dependencies. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to use **`virtual environment`** and install `django-background-task` package inside that `virtual environment

Comment: Yes I am using virtual env. only. But still it is not working :(

Comment: Seems you are using python 2.7 virtual env. Create a new one from Python 3.x and try again

Comment: All of my environments are based on Python2.7 at this moment. I thought that module was supported in 2.7 as well as stated in their docs.

Comment: Anyway, try to create a new virtual env(python 2.7) and try again

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Can any expert in python reply to this?!